# Gollum wiki github - Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit

Tags: github, gollum-wiki

I have problems using Gollum wiki with github remote wiki pages.

I created a wiki for this [project](https://github.com/ricardogarfe/python-sample-test), and Create Wiki pages in [wiki git repo](https://github.com/ricardogarfe/python-sample-test/wiki).

Clone the repo using ssh:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:ricardogarfe/python-sample-test.wiki.git
```

Install Gollum:

```
$ sudo gem install gollum
```

Run gollum inside wiki repository:

```
$ cd python-sample-test.wiki.git
$ gollum
```

Edit home page and save with comments.

Then I ran:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
# nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

So I can't do push to origin when I edit wiki pages using gollum.
I forget any configuration ? user, groups in linux to make commits, push automaticaly through gollum ?

Using:

- ruby 1.8.7
- gem 1.8.15

Thanks!
Ricardo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked with gollum so this may be a bit off base, but your output indicates that there is a commit which hasn't been pushed yet:

```
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
```

If you look at the output of `git log -p -1` does it appear to contain the changes you made? If so, just `git push` and you should be set.

Comment: thanks ! I didn't understand git message, `git push` worked.

_more eyes more solutions_

regards.